# Will this VBSCRIPT code trigger the message box?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm looking through at an old Classic ASP page that uses VBScript. The code below appears to use a variable stored in the config (global.asa) called called CODES_TIMESTAMP. However looking at the servers in question it appears that that variable no longer exists. My question is, if that variable is not defined in the config file then will the error message box be activated?

```
Dim DB_TIMESTAMP_CODES

DB_TIMESTAMP_CODES = "<%=Application("CODES_TIMESTAMP")%>"
    If trim(DB_TIMESTAMP_CODES) = "" Then
      msgbox "Setup Error... Codes are not Defined"
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, if that variable is not defined in the config file then will the error message box be activated?

Value will be "". But `msgbox` cannot be executed on ASP web page. `msgbox` will appear only from VBS script.

> The code below appears to use a variable stored in the config (global.asa) called called CODES_TIMESTAMP

You (previous developer) could assign value to `Application` variable from any page. I suggest you to make full search over all .ASP pages, may be this value assigned not in `GLOBAL.ASA`

Comment: As Zam said server side VBScript can't open a message box client side directly (although you can get it to write a JavaScript into the page to do an alert) and client side vbscript is deprecated no longer supported in IE11 in Edge mode, see msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384057(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Dijkgraaf you'll be surprised how many people/companies are still using IE8, 7, and even 6. So although sad and bad, client side VBScript is still used. Every time I go to my bank I see it and want to make some snarky remarks, lol.

Comment: @ShadowWizard + including gov organization around the world

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, I'm not surprised at all as I work in the IT industry.  But if you are making changes to code or doing new code, then you have to be aware of what will and won't work in some browsers.

Comment: perhaps that is reason why old Internet Explorer still included in W10